# Transitive dependency problem with JBPM, JBoss and RestEasy?

Tags: java, maven, resteasy, jbpm, jboss-eap-7

My code seems to be breaking on a transitive dependency issue that I cannot find.  I am trying to migrate from JBoss EAP 7.3 with RedHat's PAM 7.9 product (which is JBPM 7.48) to JBoss EAP 7.4 with PAM 7.12 (ie JBPM 7.59) and am experiencing the issue in a servlet of mine that calls the kie-server via a kie-client API.  I have read about and encountered RESTEasy issues before with JBoss, so based upon my error have removed the  tags to hopefully avoid any inconsistencies - but still have an odd error.

This is the stack trace that I get which has been edited for brevity:

```
5:37:57,975 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /PamHelper/pam/helper/pamQuery: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _typeCache
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
 ...
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
 ...
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
...
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _typeCache
        at org.kie.server.api.marshalling.json.FallbackableTypeFactory.withFallbackClassLoader(FallbackableTypeFactory.java:62)
        at org.kie.server.api.marshalling.json.JSONMarshaller.configureMarshaller(JSONMarshaller.java:284)
        at org.kie.server.api.marshalling.json.JSONMarshaller.<init>(JSONMarshaller.java:180)
        at org.kie.server.api.marshalling.BaseMarshallerBuilder.build(BaseMarshallerBuilder.java:45)
        at org.kie.server.api.marshalling.MarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(MarshallerFactory.java:50)
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.<init>(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:84)
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.KieServicesClientImpl.<init>(KieServicesClientImpl.java:74)
        at org.kie.server.client.KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(KieServicesFactory.java:101)
```

This is my dependency tree.  I have guessing there is a conflict either in a RestEasy dependency or (from the error message) some odd problem initializing marshalling; there is no typeCache field either in my code or the JBPM source code.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ PamServer ---
[INFO] com.gok.ams:PamServer:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.gok.ams:ams-pam-util:jar:0.0.12-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.5.8.Final-redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0.GA-redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.12.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7.redhat-7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final-redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final-redhat-00003:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.gok.ams:ams-pam-workitemhandlers:jar:2.0.6.41-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.gok.ams:amsObjectModel:jar:0.0.65-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.jbpm:jbpm-workitems-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie.soup:kie-soup-xstream:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-core-reflective:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.kie:kie-memory-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.drools:drools-core-dynamic:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.jbpm:jbpm-flow:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-mvel:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-serialization-protobuf:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie.soup:kie-soup-commons:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie.soup:kie-soup-project-datamodel-commons:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.kie.soup:kie-soup-project-datamodel-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie:kie-dmn-feel:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.8.0.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:jar:3.13.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.drools:drools-mvel-parser:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.obermuhlner:big-math:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie:kie-dmn-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-dmn-backend:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.drools:drools-ruleunit:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.drools:drools-alphanetwork-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jpmml:pmml-model:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.jpmml:pmml-agent:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.4.12.Final-redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jbpm:jbpm-bpmn2:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-ecj:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jbpm:jbpm-flow-builder:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie:kie-internal:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie:kie-dmn-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.kie:kie-dmn-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.7.0.redhat-00003:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:ST4:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jbpm:jbpm-services-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] +- org.kie:kie-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.kie.soup:kie-soup-maven-support:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] +- org.kie.server:kie-server-client:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-canonical-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.drools:drools-model-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.drools:drools-mvel-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1.redhat-3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11.redhat-00004:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.0.0.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.18.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie.server:kie-server-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-xstream:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-common:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-jaxb:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.12.1.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-dependencies:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-commons:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-compiler-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-compiler-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-compiler-commons:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-evaluator-api:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-evaluator-core:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-evaluator-assembler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-kie-internal:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-common:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-regression-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-regression-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-regression-evaluator:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-tree-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-tree-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-tree-evaluator:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.kie:kie-pmml-compiler-api:jar:tests:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-scorecard-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-scorecard-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-drools-scorecard-evaluator:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-mining-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-mining-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-mining-evaluator:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-clustering-model:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-clustering-compiler:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.kie:kie-pmml-models-clustering-evaluator:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.drools:kie-pmml:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.kie.server:kie-server-common:jar:7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:4.0.3.redhat-00002:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.jms:jakarta.jms-api:jar:2.0.3.redhat-00001:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.3.0.redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30.redhat-00001:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.4.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer:jar:6.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core:jar:6.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm.async:asyncutil:jar:0.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:6.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client-api:jar:6.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core-spi:jar:6.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.16:test
```

And this is the dependency part of my pom.xml not related to testing.

```
    <properties>
        <version.org.kie>7.59.0.Final-redhat-00006</version.org.kie>
        <!--version.org.kie>7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004</version.org.kie-->
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <version.org.slf4j>1.7.26</version.org.slf4j>
        <jax-rs-version>3.0.14.Final</jax-rs-version>
        <version.object.model>0.0.65-SNAPSHOT</version.object.model>
        <version.utils>0.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version.utils>
        <version.workItemHandlers>2.0.6.41-SNAPSHOT</version.workItemHandlers>
        <version.jakarta.persistence-api>2.2.3</version.jakarta.persistence-api>
        <version.resteasy>6.0.0.Final</version.resteasy>
        <!--version.jackson>2.12.4.redhat-00001</version.jackson-->
        <version.jackson>2.12.3</version.jackson>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>  
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jackson}</version> 
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jackson}</version> 
         <!--scope>provided</scope-->
       </dependency>    
      <dependency>
         <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
         <version>${version.jakarta.persistence-api}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gok.ams</groupId>
        <artifactId>ams-pam-util</artifactId>
        <version>${version.utils}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>ams-pam-workitemhandlers</artifactId>
        <version>${version.workItemHandlers}</version>
        <groupId>com.gok.ams</groupId>
      </dependency>       
      <dependency>  
          <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
          <artifactId>jbpm-workitems-core</artifactId>
          <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
         <artifactId>jbpm-services-api</artifactId>
         <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
      </dependency>                     
    
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>${version.org.slf4j}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.14.Final</version> 
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
          <version>${version.resteasy}</version> 
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
          <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
          <version>${version.resteasy}</version> 
      </dependency>
```

The other possibility that I can think of is that this is related to [this issue which may not have been fixed in PAM](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-wb-common/pull/3685) ; I have downgraded from Java 11 to Java 8 to have my the code running on my laptop look more like my company's integration environment.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a dependency on two different versions of RESTEasy. You don't want to use 6.0.0.Final as that is Jakarta REST 3.0 which is Jakarta EE 9.1. You want to use the latest 3.15.x version as that is what JBoss EAP 7.4 uses. You also want to make sure you mark those dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>` as they are provided by JBoss EAP 7.4.

I don't think you need the `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer` at either.